# Why some function in the class don't run by itself when updating in python

Tags: python, function, class, kivy

I'm following kivy tutorial to create Galaxy app, but I wonder why the "update_vertical_lines(self)" need to be called in another function (here is "on_size(self,*args)") to run when it got updated (resizing itself when running). I have no idea if this is a loop question because I don't know what the keywords are.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Line

class MainWidget(Widget):
    perspective_point_x = NumericProperty(0)
    perspective_point_y = NumericProperty(0)
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.init_vertical_lines()
        
    def on_parent(self,widget,parent):
        pass
    
    def on_size(self,*args):
        print(self.width,self.height)
        #self.perspective_point_x = self.width/2
        #self.perspective_point_y = self.height*0.75
        self.update_vertical_lines() # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        
    def on_perspective_point_x(self,widget,value):
        pass
    
    def on_perspective_point_y(self,widget,value):
        pass
    
    def init_vertical_lines(self):
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1,1,1)
            self.line = Line(points=(100,0,100,100))
    
    def update_vertical_lines(self): # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        center_x = self.width/2
        self.line.points = (center_x,0,center_x,100)
class GalaxyApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GalaxyApp().run()
```

Comment: `update_vertical_lines` is not a name that has any built-in meaning to Kivy - the only way that method is ever going to be called is if you explicitly call it.  `on_size`, however, is a standard event handler method - it is automatically called whenever the widget is resized.  The code in `update_vertical_lines()` could have been placed directly in `on_size()`, but whoever wrote this code chose to move it to a separate function - perhaps for clarity, perhaps because they expected to need to call it from more than one place.

Comment: Thanks a lot, according to your answer I have just found more information about my question: https://github.com/YingLiu4203/LearningKivy/blob/master/Ch05%20Events%20and%20Properties/Events%20and%20Properties.md